# How to put regex match to the end of line in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have some lines. I want to search for a regex in these lines and append the match to the end of matching lines. For example, this is input:

```
foo x
```

Here is the expected output:

```
foo x foo
```

I can use a substitute command to achieve this conversion:

```
%s/\(f\w*\).*/\0 \1/
```

But I think this solution is sometimes too difficult to apply or to adapt to some use cases. I look for a simpler solution using global command similar to that:

```
g/\f\w*/ s/$/ <??>/
```

I want to filter the lines first. Then use the match in each line in substitute command. Is there a command that lets me use the match in global command in place of `<??>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access the matched text from another command. I think it is easier to match your desired content and then match to the end of line (with `.*`) and re-start the match there with `\zs`. Like this, for example:

```
:%s/\v(regex).*\zs/ \1
```

In this command, you restarted the position of the match after all the line was captured, but also your desired text was saved in `\1`.

Comment: @Mert overall I think this can vary a lot depending on your regex. Well, this here is just an idea.